# How do I return to FirstViewController when all the questions is asked without app crash?

Tags: swift

I think I miss something in my codes. When I have pressed "next" for all the 50 images, the app crash. How do I stop the app crash? When the last question is asked, I want it to return to FirstViewController. Where do I miss out on my codes? See the pictures below (PRESS THE LINKS).
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfI1C.jpg) (Codes)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7bSo.png) (Simulator screenshot)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using a UIViewcontroller for each image, try using a UIImageview on one view controller and add an arrow button for "next". This way, within the swift file you could give a variable a number and increment it by 1 every time, then when it reaches 50, you can reset it to zero.

There's a great exercise on this in Apples free I-Book: "Intro to App development" Chapter-18 pg.156